# Present Value Formula using the FV and Payments

Tags: sql-server, excel

In Excel, if I enter `=PV(8%/12,12,-1970,0,0)` I will get $22,647
The formula for this is:

```
select  @PAYMENT * (Power((1 + @RATE / 100),@NPER) -1) / (((@RATE / 100)) * Power((1 + @RATE / 100),@NPER))
```

What would be the formula if I want to add the `FV(Future Value)`?

Answer (score 1):

The formula to use to replicate Excel's formula PV(8%/12,12,-1970,456300,0):

select ( @PAYMENT * (Power((1 + @RATE / 100),@NPER) -1) /  (((@RATE / 100)) * Power((1 + @RATE / 100),@NPER))  + @FV / Power((1 + @RATE / 100),@NPER) ) * -1

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that just be a compound interest calculation, id FV=CV(R+1)^N? ie:

```
select @CurrentValue * power(1+@RATE,@NPER)
```

Comment: Could you provide entire formula?  I can check if the results match what Excel calculates